# sencha architect 2 folders in View

Tags: sencha-architect

Is possibility (in sencha architect 2) to add folders into View, controller, model and in this folders keep files? It will be help to manage in big project. In plus button I don't see possibility to add any folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be straight forward and exact, the answer is **NO**. Sencha Architect is a powerful tool when it comes to making things easy in Sencha and structuring your MVC files related to your project (Like your JS, CSS files) but there is no way you can add other files within the structure using Sencha Architect.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a prefix on each component name, example:

accounts.MainWindow

Will be generated as

/app/views/accounts/MainWindow.js